# ReactDOM.hydrate() not working after initial SSR (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, react-router

After my initial server-side render of the application, my onClick event (on a button in my Homepage.js component) is not executing. It seems my ReactDom.hydrate() in my client.js file is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated! You can go to the following repo for whole code base https://github.com/thegreekjester/React_SSR.

Steps to run and reproduce the issue:

- npm install
- npm run dev
- open `localhost:3000` in browser
- Click on the button that appears
- You should see some message in the console but you don't

homepage.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class HomePage extends React.Component{

    exampleMethod(){
      console.log('Shit is going down')
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <h1>{this.props.state.attributes.name}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => this.exampleMethod()}> Console log some text </button>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({state:state.optimizelyReducer});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  dataFileManager: (timing, id, attributes) => dispatch({type:'USER_SERVICE', id:id, attributes:attributes},
                               dispatch({type:'DATAFILE_MANAGER', timing:timing})),
  updateAttr: (attr) => dispatch({type:'UPDATE_ATTR', attr:attr, value:value})
});

HomePage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);



export default HomePage;
```

client.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './App.js'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__

const store = configureStore(window.__PRELOADED_STATE__);

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <ReduxProvider store={store}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
  </ReduxProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

server.js:

```js
import 'babel-polyfill'
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router'
import bodyparser from 'body-parser'
import App from './src/App.js'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore.js'


const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000


app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.use(express.static('build/public'));

function handleRender(req, res){
  const store = configureStore()
  const context = {}
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App/>
    </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  )

  const preloadedState = store.getState()
  res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
}

function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState){
  return  `
          <html>
          <head>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div id='root'>${html}</div>
            <script>window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState)}</script>
            <script type='babel' src='client_bundle.js'></script>
          </body>
          </html>`

}

app.use(handleRender)



app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`React SSR App is running on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

Webpack.client.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {

  // production || development
  mode: 'development',

  // Inform webpack that we're building a bundle
  // for nodeJS, rather then for the browser
  target: 'node',

  // Tell webpack the root file of our
  // server application
  entry: './src/client.js',

  // Tell webpack where to put the output file
  // that is generated
  output: {
    filename: 'client_bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/public'),
    publicPath: '/build/public'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        options: {
          presets: [
            'react', 'stage-0', ['env', {
              target: 'web'
            }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Webpack.server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {

  // production || development
  mode: 'development',

  // Inform webpack that we're building a bundle
  // for nodeJS, rather then for the browser
  target: 'node',

  // Tell webpack the root file of our
  // server application
  entry: './server.js',

  // Tell webpack where to put the output file
  // that is generated
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        options: {
          presets: [
            'react', 'stage-0', ['env', {
              target: { browsers: ['last 2 versions']}
            }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  // Tell webpack not to bundle any libraries that exist in the 'node_modules' folder
  // into the server bundle
  externals: [webpackNodeExternals()]

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of points you have to check:

- Why did you use `target: 'node'` in your client webpack config?
- Whats up with the `<script type='babel' src='client_bundle.js'></script>`? Why type babel?
- Also you may need `babel-polyfill` in your client entries depending on how you compile your javascript.

Comment: Hello! If I don't put type='babel' on my client_bundle.js script it causes a reference error to occur.

Comment: That is because the script tag is otherwise not even loaded. The error is `require not defined` or something along those lines if I remember correctly.